# GXTest - No se genera TestResults*.xml en jobs jenkins con errores en pruebas

Tags: genexus

En un pipeline de Jenkins, el job de GXTest no genera el archivo TestResults*.xml si se encuentran errores en las pruebas.

¿Que puede estar ocurriendo? ¿Un problema de la versión?

Job Jenkins MSBuild:

```
/t:RunAllTests
/p:TestType="Unit"
/p:KBPath="X:\MyKB"
/p:GX_PROGRAM_DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus16"
/p:EnvironmentName="DevNet"
/p:GXServerUser="${GXServerUser}" /p:GXServerPass="${GXServerPass}"
/p:JUnitTestFilePath="$WORKSPACE"
/p:AllowFailedTests="True"
/p:DetailedResults="True"
```

> GeneXus 16 - Version: 16.0.138086 U7 GXTest 0.6.2

Salida de consola final de Jenkins:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]